# How to stop replacing single quote ' in apex with space

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

I am trying to replace all characters expect below mention characters with space in Apex
`[A-Z a-z 0-9-,.&/'@()+# $: ]`

```
String customerName = jo&hn<>ji'o;
String AccName = customerName.replaceAll('[^0-9a-zA-Z\\&.,'-/@+():$#]',' ');
system.debug('AccName' + AccName);
```

But when I am trying to add **single quote '** in the regex I am getting error.
can anyone help me on this issue.

Thanks In Advance!!

Answer (score 3):

Since Apex uses single quotes for string literals, anywhere that you need to use a single quote you need to escape it.

In many other languages, you'd just use a single backslash (i.e. `\'`)
In Apex though, you need to use two backslashes (`\\'`).

Apex treats a single backslash as the start of an "escape sequence". `\n` is the most common one, which tells Apex to replace those two characters with a line break. It's used to print ASCII characters that are "unprintable".

Since `\'` is not a valid escape sequence, we need to tell Apex to not treat it as an escape sequence. That's the function of the second backslash.